# Show AD Group members for each AD groups in each own Out-GridView

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wish to modify the code below to show the AD group members of the Group names that match the input pattern and show it in each own Out-GridView window.

It works for one single AD group with the exact name, but not with ***GroupNam****

This is the code:

```
function Get-GroupNamesFromInputbox ([string]$Title) {
    do {
        $GroupNames = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::Inputbox("Enter Group Names, or nothing (Press ESC) to leave", "Enter partial group name to search", $Title)
        # On Cancel the InputBox function simply returns an empty string.
        # in that case, just return $null so the calling code can handle it
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($GroupNames)) { return $null }

        # Check if the user can be found
        $Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*$GroupNames*'" –Properties Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if (!$Groups) {
            # If not found, show the same InputBox again until a valid 
            # accountname was given or the dialog is cancelled.
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The group name similar like '$GroupNames' does not exist!")
        }
    }
    while (!$Groups)

    return $Groups
}
# Retrieve all possible AD Groups an store it inside the $GroupNames
$GroupNames = Get-GroupNamesFromInputbox

$properties = @('Name', 'DisplayName', 'title', 'telephoneNumber', 'MobilePhone', 'lastLogonTimestamp', 'userprincipalname', 'CanonicalName', 'DistinguishedName', 'lastlogondate', 'mail', 'proxyAddresses', 'Manager')

# Show the result in each separate Out-GridView window
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive |
        Get-ADUser -properties $properties |
            Select-Object Name, 
                Title,
                telephoneNumber,
                MobilePhone,
                @{Label = "UPN"; Expression = { $_.userprincipalname.split("@")[1] } },
                @{Label = 'Manager'; Expression = { $_.Manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$' } },
                @{Label = "OU Location"; Expression = { Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Parent } }, 
                @{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = { ($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object { ($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(':')[1] }) -join ', ' } },
                LastLogonDate,
                @{n = 'LastLogonDaysAgo'; e = { [int]((Get-Date) - $_.LastLogonDate).TotalDays } },
                @{n = 'CN'; e = { Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Parent } },
                @{n = "LastLogon"; e = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp) } } |
                Sort-Object Name | Out-GridView -Title "$($Group) group member(s) are:"
}
```

The error code when I enter the partial group name for the two groups **IT Support Management** and **IT Support Team** is like:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'IT Su*' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'IT Su*' -Recursive
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EFT Sol*:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the -Identity parameter for `Get-ADGroupMember` does not support wildcards, but only complete SIDs, SamAccountNames or ObjectIDs.

You will need to either modify the `Get-GroupNamesFromInputBox` function to do something like a `Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like "IT Su*"'` before assigning them to the $GroupNames variable or do a similar kind of lookup at a later stage.

I'd probably do it in the function as that would also allow you to give feedback to the user if no groups are found.

Comment: Already done @Laage, it is still not opening the Out-GridView in each own window?

Comment: What type do you get if you run `$Groups.GetType()` before the ForEach loop? And what happens if you just strip the foreach loop to the absolute basics? `foreach ($Group in $Groups){$Group | Out-GridView}`?